# How to handle selecting row in TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, tableview

in this app, when you select the second option 'green' it will print "green", but when you search for green and it appears at index 0, and you click on it, it will print "red". how do i get it to print "green" no mater what index and row green is on the table view?

thanks...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let sampleData:[String] = ["red", "green", "blue", "brown", "black", "white", "purple", "silver"]
    var dataToDisplay:[String]!

    var searchController:UISearchController!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.dataToDisplay = self.sampleData

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self


        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataToDisplay.count
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Basic") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.dataToDisplay[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }


    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        let searchString:String = searchController.searchBar.text

        self.dataToDisplay = self.sampleData.filter ({ (dataString:String) -> Bool in

            let match = dataString.rangeOfString(searchString)

            if match != nil {
            return true
            }
            else {
            return false
            }





        })

        self.tableView.reloadData()




    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.tableView.hidden = false
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.tableView.hidden = false
    }

    func didDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.tableView.hidden = false
    }





 func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

        if indexPath.row == 1 {

        println("green")

        }
 if indexPath.row == 0 {

        println("red")

        }
}
```

Comment: Use the data at the selected row (not the row#). That's what cellForRowAtIndexPath is doing and didSelectRowAtIndexPath can do the same with a single println.

Comment: Please Be More Specific. Can you please write sample code?

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can just put this one line: `println("\(self.dataToDisplay[indexPath.row])")`

Answer (score 0):

I Figued out the answer...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {



   var rownumber = indexPath.row

    if   dataToDisplay[rownumber] == sampleData[0] {
   println("red")

    }
```

}